# How to push more than one value into the form?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I want to push an array of inputs into a form. At the moment I always get with a `console.log`only the latest inputted value. How can I push all the input values? I just wonder If I even need a additional form arrays. Since I can output the whole list in my console. So I have access to this data which is imported in order to upload to a server.

page.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addTag(form.value)">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="tag" clearInput="true" placeholder="Tags" [(ngModel)]="tagInput" name="tagValue"></ion-input>
      <ion-button item-right type="submit" icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
  </form>
  <ion-chip *ngFor="let tag of tagList; let i = index">
      <ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>{{ tag }}</ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="close-circle" (click)="removeChip(i)"></ion-icon>
  </ion-chip>
```

page.ts

```
form: FormGroup;

public tagList: any[] = [];

constructor() { }

addTag(formValue) {
    if (this.tagInput !== '') {  //no empty input
    this.tagList.push(formValue.tagValue);
    this.tagInput = '';
    }
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      tag: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'submit',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.minLength(1)]
      })
    });
  }

  confirm() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
```

Comment: Or don't I even need this approach since my inputs are stored in the tagList anyways ?

Comment: can you explain more about your problem? In angular forms, we have form arrays. But I am not sure whether you are asking about angular form arrays. So please explain your problem a little bit more.

Comment: NOT use [(ngModel)] in a ReactiveForm. If you want use an array in ReactiveForm -your code don't say that, only the question- you must use FormArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, based on your code, you actually have a form and an array of items added from the form... not sure why you need a form array or anything like that. Your fixed code could just be like this:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addTag()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="tag" clearInput="true" placeholder="Tags" name="tagValue"></ion-input>
      <ion-button item-right type="submit" icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
  </form>
  <ion-chip *ngFor="let tag of tagList; let i = index">
      <ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>{{ tag }}</ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="close-circle" (click)="removeChip(i)"></ion-icon>
  </ion-chip>
```

get rid of the mixing of reactive forms and template forms, and just call add tag, don't pass a value in.

```
  form: FormGroup;

  public tagList: any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  addTag() { // properly access and reset reactive form values
    const tagCtrl = this.form.get('tag');
    if (tagCtrl.value) {
      this.tagList.push(tagCtrl.value);
      this.tagCtrl.reset(''); // reset() sets the value and resets validation
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      tag: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'submit',
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.minLength(1)]
      })
    });
  }

  confirm() {
    console.log(this.tagList); // just check your tagList instead of looking at the form
  }
```

you're overthinking it here. a FormArray could be useful under some circumstances, like needing some complex validation / error message capability, or ability to edit tags after adding them, but if simple remove is all you need, you're over engineering this.